# insert into pdf a select statement

Tags: java

i have a select in my db and i would print the repose of my select into a pdf.

How can i make this. I have more than 1 line.

i have this code but this doesn't work.

```
st = con.createStatement();
                          rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT id_ecole,id_eleve,id_doss FROM jonction");
                             while(rs.next()){              
                            nom_eleve = rs.getInt("id_ecole");
                             prenom_eleve = rs.getInt ("id_eleve");
                             id_doss = rs.getInt("id_doss");
                             id_doss1=Integer.toString(id_doss);
                              st = con.createStatement();
                            rs2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT nom_ecole FROM ecole WHERE id_ecole= ('"+nom_eleve+"')");
                             rs2.next();
                             nom_ecole = rs2.getString("nom_ecole");
                              st = con.createStatement();
                            rs3 = st.executeQuery("SELECT nom_eleve,prenom_eleve FROM eleve WHERE id_eleve= ('"+prenom_eleve+"') ");
                             rs3.next(); 
                             nom_eleve1 = rs3.getString("nom_eleve");
                             prenom_eleve1 = rs3.getString("prenom_eleve"); 

                       /*File   fichier_dossard = new File(path_doss);
                       FileWriter  fichier_ecris = new FileWriter(fichier_dossard, true);
                       BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fichier_ecris);
                       PrintWriter ecrire_fichier = new PrintWriter (buffer);
                       if(fichier_dossard.exists() == false){
                           fichier_dossard.createNewFile();
                       }
                       ecrire_fichier.print(nom_ecole+Newligne);
                       ecrire_fichier.print(nom_eleve1+" "+prenom_eleve1+Newligne);
                       ecrire_fichier.print(id_doss + Newligne);
                       ecrire_fichier.print(Newligne);
                       ecrire_fichier.close();*/

                       PdfWriter Writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path_doss));
                       document.open();
                        PdfContentByte cb =Writer.getDirectContent();
           document.add(new Paragraph(nom_ecole,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,40)));
           document.add(new Paragraph(nom_eleve1+" "+prenom_eleve1,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,40)));
           codebarre.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
           codebarre.setCode(id_doss1);
           document.add(codebarre.createImageWithBarcode(cb,BaseColor.BLACK,BaseColor.BLACK));
           document.add(para);

                             //fin dossard
                       }
```

document.close();

Thanks

Comment: How does it not work? Note that you're opening the document for each iteration of the loop but only closing it once, outside the loop.

Comment: So i have to open before my loop and close after my loop ?